# 'Smaller than A and B' or 'Smaller than A or B'?

Tags: sentence-construction

- If the height of a shim is smaller than the thicknesses of B and C, it will be buried and you cannot take it out.

The shim is inserted between B and C, vertically. I don't want the shim height to be smaller than both B and C.

- Height of shim > thickness of B
- Height of shim > thickness of C

In this case, is it more appropriate to say "B or C"?
Please let me know if there are better ways to say it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that *A*’s thickness exceeds the larger of *B*’s and *C*’s?

Comment: sorry it was wrong. I was not intended to write A. I edited the question.

Comment: The fact that you've used the word ***both*** is crucial here. It's perfectly valid to refer to something being (or you not *wanting* it to be) ***smaller than both B and C***. But ***smaller than both B or C*** can *never* appear as a valid sequence in English, no matter what the context or intended meaning.

Comment: Ok! "both B and C".I got it. Thank you!

Comment: [*Ganymede, one of the moons of Jupiter, is **bigger than both Mercury and Pluto.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Ganymede+one+of+the+moons+of+Jupiter%2C+is+bigger+than+both%22) That's perfectly valid English, but perhaps *some* people might think it could be misunderstood as meaning *bigger than Mercury and Pluto **combined*** (it doesn't). But no-one could misunderstand [*with a diameter of 5262 km (Ganymede) is **bigger than Mercury or Pluto***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+a+diameter+of+5262+km+it+is+bigger+than+Mercury+or+Pluto%22), which means the same.

Comment: Thank you. Is it"Ganymede with a diameter of 5262 km is bigger than Mercury or Pluto"? or is it starts with "with"? So "bigger than both A and B" means the same as "bigger than A or B"?

Comment: Both versions assert the same astronomical truth, from which it follows that ***bigger than both Mercury and Pluto*** and ***bigger than Mercury or Pluto*** mean exactly the same thing. The ***or*** version is usually better, because it can't be misunderstood, but some people sometimes will prefer the ***and*** version because it can be more emphatic (even more so if ***both*** is included, which you *cannot* do with ***or***).

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it!

Answer (score 0):

To make it less ambiguous you could go for "thicknesses of B and of C". This makes it clear what you mean. "Thicknesses of B or C" is grammatically correct and maybe more elegant, but in technical documentation clarity and lack of ambiguity are more important.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry my question was messed up. I'll use "of B and of C"!

Comment: Don't worry about the question. It reads fine to me as it is now.

Comment: Avoiding ambiguity is why I suggested *exceeds the larger of B’s and C’s*.

Comment: I didn't know the phrase "exceeds the larger of". I think it's useful to make my sentence clear. Thank you.